"TypePtr does not name a type after" including 'typedefs.h'
I'm writing a project for univeristy. I wrote a function Vehicle.getActualCost(), tested it in VehicleTest.cpp and everything is working smoothly.
Problem occurs when in these tests I change Vehicle* to VehiclePtr as per professor's instruction.
VehiclePtr is a type declared in typedefs.h file, which looks like this:
#ifndef CARRENTAL_TYPEDEFS_H
#define CARRENTAL_TYPEDEFS_H

#include "model/Client.h"
#include "model/Address.h"
#include "model/Rent.h"
#include "model/Vehicle.h"

typedef Address* AddressPtr;

class Rent;
typedef Rent* RentPtr;

class Client;
typedef Client* ClientPtr;

typedef Vehicle* VehiclePtr;

#endif //CARRENTAL_TYPEDEFS_H

After which I get errors like these:
In file included from /mnt/c/Users/szindzeks/CLionProjects/atom_cz_1215_03/majkowski/workshop/library/include/model/Client.h:8,
                 from /mnt/c/Users/szindzeks/CLionProjects/atom_cz_1215_03/majkowski/workshop/library/include/typedefs.h:8,
                 from /mnt/c/Users/szindzeks/CLionProjects/atom_cz_1215_03/majkowski/workshop/library/test/VehicleTest.cpp:6:
/mnt/c/Users/szindzeks/CLionProjects/atom_cz_1215_03/majkowski/workshop/library/include/model/Rent.h:24:5: error: ‘ClientPtr’ does not name a type
   24 |     ClientPtr client;
      |     ^~~~~~~~~
/mnt/c/Users/szindzeks/CLionProjects/atom_cz_1215_03/majkowski/workshop/library/include/model/Rent.h:26:5: error: ‘VehiclePtr’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘Vehicle’?
   26 |     VehiclePtr vehicle;
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~
      |     Vehicle
/mnt/c/Users/szindzeks/CLionProjects/atom_cz_1215_03/majkowski/workshop/library/include/model/Rent.h:40:33: error: ‘ClientPtr’ has not been declared
   40 |     Rent(const unsigned int id, ClientPtr client, VehiclePtr vehicle, pt::ptime beginTime);
      |                                 ^~~~~~~~~
/mnt/c/Users/szindzeks/CLionProjects/atom_cz_1215_03/majkowski/workshop/library/include/model/Rent.h:40:51: error: ‘VehiclePtr’ has not been declared
   40 |     Rent(const unsigned int id, ClientPtr client, VehiclePtr vehicle, pt::ptime beginTime);
      |                                                   ^~~~~~~~~~

...

Client.h
#ifndef CARRENTAL_CLIENT_H
#define CARRENTAL_CLIENT_H

#include "Rent.h"
#include "typedefs.h"
#include <vector>

class Client {

private:
    std::string firstName;
    std::string lastName;
    const std::string personalID;
    AddressPtr address;
    std::vector<Rent*> currentRents;

public:
    Client(const std::string &firstName, const std::string &lastName, const std::string &personalID, AddressPtr address);
    ~Client();

    std::string getInfo() const;
    std::string getFullInfo() const;
    const std::string &getFirstName() const;
    const std::string &getLastName() const;
    const std::string &getPersonalID() const;
    const AddressPtr getAddress() const;
    const std::vector<RentPtr> & getCurrentRents() const;

    void setFirstName(const std::string &firstName);
    void setLastName(const std::string &lastName);
    void setAddress(AddressPtr address);

    void addNewRent(RentPtr newRent);
    void removeRent(unsigned int rentID);
    void removeRent(RentPtr rentToRemove);

};

#endif //CARRENTAL_CLIENT_H

Rent.h
#ifndef CARRENTAL_RENT_H
#define CARRENTAL_RENT_H

#include "Vehicle.h"
#include "Client.h"
#include "typedefs.h"
#include <boost/date_time.hpp>
#include <math.h>

namespace pt = boost::posix_time;
namespace gr = boost::gregorian;

class Rent {
private:
    const unsigned int id;
    ClientPtr client;
    VehiclePtr vehicle;
    unsigned int rentCost = 0;
    pt::ptime beginTime;
    pt::ptime endTime = pt::not_a_date_time;

public:
    Rent(const unsigned int id, ClientPtr client, VehiclePtr vehicle, pt::ptime beginTime);

    const unsigned int getId() const;
    const ClientPtr getClient() const;
    const VehiclePtr getVehicle() const;
    const pt::ptime &getBeginTime() const;
    const pt::ptime &getEndTime() const;

    std::string getInfo() const;
    unsigned int getRentDays() const;
    unsigned int getRentCost() const;
    void endRent(pt::ptime endTime);

};

#endif //CARRENTAL_RENT_H

And the VehicleTest.cpp
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>
#include "model/Bicycle.h"
#include "model/MotorVehicle.h"
#include "model/Car.h"
#include "model/Moped.h"
#include "typedefs.h"

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE(TestSuiteVehicle)

    ...

    BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(VehicleActualPriceTests){
        VehiclePtr vehicle = new Vehicle("E", 1000);
        ...
        VehiclePtr car5 = new Car("E", 1000, 2500, E);

        BOOST_TEST(vehicle->getActualRentalPrice() == vehicle->getBasePrice());
        BOOST_TEST(bicycle->getActualRentalPrice() == bicycle->getBasePrice());
        ...
        BOOST_TEST(car5->getActualRentalPrice() == (int)(car5->getBasePrice() * 1.5 *  1.5));

        delete vehicle;
        ...
        delete car5;
    }

I of course expected for it to work no problem after #inlucde "typedefs.h", but it didn't.
I tried different #include variations, changing the typedefs.h file but the effect was even worse or the same.
The program compiles and work as expected. The tests however, do not compile.
I'd be really thankful if someone was able to help me.

Is the typedefs.h you posted exactly as the prof gave it to you?  I would assume it would have none of the includes, and it would have forward declarations before each typedef.

Side notes : Don't use raw pointers in C++ (and try to avoid pointers as much as you can, use containers and move semantics). If your classes don't have virtual methods new is not needed. And if you need to allocate polymorphic classes use std::make_unique. The typedefs really don't add anything to the readability of your code so I would just remove them

@ChrisMM The prof just told us to do make a typedefs.h file and figure it out ourselves. I'll try and do it as you as and get back to you.

@Pepijn Kramer. The raw pointers will be replaced with smart pointers in the next stage of the project, a follow an instruction for that project, but I didn't reach that stage yet. Thanks for the suggestion though!

@ChrisMM it worked! Thank you so much! I clearly had a wrong idea of how typedefs.h file is supposed to work.

@KacperMajkowski Your teacher is probably teaching you datastructures right? That usually involves a very messy way of using C++ (so be prepared to unlearn a lot later). Can you show your professor those two things : c++ core guidelines and Stop teaching "C". He is also welocme to talk to us here too ;) (By the way stop teaching "C" might be fun for you to watch too)

@PepijnKramer I'd like to, but it's more complicated than that. My current prof teaches us OOP and some of it's principles and the learning materials he made for his students are in my opinion quite good and thorough for the most part. His style of teaching evolves around the fact, that on previous semester we were taught in this C oriented manner, and that is caused by the fact, that a substantial part of students actually come from middle schools where they have C or "C++" classes and they were already taught on how to do things, like you would do them in C and not in C++.

So basically my opinion (and my profs it seems) is that education system in my country should have to be improved on many levels in order to not teach those things based on C, as it is correct to assume people who take the specific courses I take right now already come with some background in programming taught in this suboptimal manner. btw. we had data structures and algos course in previous semester, it was not particularly advanced, but also thorough and hands-on for the people actually willing to learn it.

The file "typedefs.h" includes headers "Rent.h" and "Vehicle.h" before declaring the typedefs.
#ifndef CARRENTAL_TYPEDEFS_H
#define CARRENTAL_TYPEDEFS_H

#include "model/Client.h"
#include "model/Address.h"
#include "model/Rent.h"
#include "model/Vehicle.h"
//.....

So the compiler issues errors because these headers use these typedefs before declaring last. At least the headers should be included after the typedefs. In the typedefs you can use elaborated class names.
